# How to update a part of oracle database table using pandas df and cx_Oracle cursor()?

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

Suppose my Oracle db table `myTable` has 10 columns and 10 rows of data with data types like below:

```
   Column         Data_Type
1  Calendarday      Date         *Primary key
2  col1              ...
.                     .
.                     .
.                     .
10 Flag             Number(1,0)
```

and suppose my pandas dataframe `df` has 2 columns and 3 rows of data:

```
Date          Bit
2000-12-21     1
2000-12-22     1
2000-12-23     1
```

Dtypes are: datetime64[ns] and int64.

Basically i want to update the `Flag` column of `myTable` with values from `Bit` in `df` where `Calendarday` is equal to `Date`. So here, i just want to overwrite 3 `Flag` records and not the entire column or the entire table. The code i am trying is:

```
cur = con.cursor()
query = '''insert into myTable (Calendarday, Flag) values (%s, %s);'''
cur.executemany(query, df[['Date', 'Bit']].values.tolist())
con.commit()
```

But executing this is giving me error:

```
cur.executemany(query, df[['Date', 'Bit']].values.tolist())
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I really don't know how to fix it. Do I need to specify the position of columns in `myTable` or could it be because of date format conversion issue between pandas and Oracle? Please skip suggesting sqlalchemy solutions. Need to do this the cursor way only. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want an Insert but a Bulk update,

First convert your Dataframe to a list of tuples. Then run your update query by passing bind parameters.

```
data = [tuple(x) for x in df[['Bit', 'Date']].values]

query="""UPDATE mytable SET flag = :bit 
          where calendarday = TO_DATE(:dt,'yyyy-mm-dd') 
      """
cur.executemany(query, data)
```

Comment: Code is working fine but it still didn't update values inside the db table? `@Kaushik`

Comment: @Prachi : It does I've tested it. Please check if the values match in your table. Also, do `conn.commit()`

Comment: I have a similar query but i get this error -> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'Action'. im using execute , not executemany. what can be the cause ?